# how to redirect sub folder query string url using htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Good Evening....

i have my site in **wordpress** and i don't want query string url to index in google search result, so for this i used below code for home page url like this

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^$ /? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
RewriteRule .? %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
```

by using the above code below url automatically redirect to home url...

http://example.com/? or http://example.com/?paramater=1

redirect on...

http://example.com

but my concern is that the above code is not working for sub folder or sub directories like..

http://example.com/folder/?paramater=1 or http://example.com/folder/?

should be redirect on..

http://example.com/folder/ or http://example.com/folder/ respectively.....

can anybody help me in order to correct above code..

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to remove query strings from urls :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [L,R=301]
```

The reason why your redirect is not working is because you are checking for empty query strings.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
```

You need to check if the query string exists

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
```

Comment: kidly give me whole code which i can replace to given code